# Не закрывается Excel в C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

В программе на C# работаю с книгой Excel следующим образом.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel;
excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Workbooks.Open( "1.xlsx");
Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
//Читаю некоторые ячейки
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close();
excel.Quit();
GC.Collect();
```

После выполнения этого кода процесс EXCEL.EXE продолжает висеть в диспетчере задач, но завершается после закрытия моей программы. Если убрать последние 3 строчки, то процесс висит в диспетчере и не завершается после закрытия моей программы. Как же правильно закрыть Excel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Необходимо освобождать все используемые COM-объекты с помощью `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`.

Кроме того, есть такое правило:

> Никогда не используйте две точки с объектами COM.

Когда вы пишете:

```
excel.Workbooks.Open( "1.xlsx");
```

тут на самом деле создаются два COM-объекта. Оба нужно освободить после окончания работы с ними. Поэтому нужно разбить это выражения на два, с сохранением каждого COM-объекта в переменной.

Кроме того, желательно предусмотреть гарантированное освобождение даже в случае исключений.
Финальный код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
Workbooks workbooks = null;
Workbook workbook = null;

try
{
    workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
    workbook = workbooks.Open( "1.xlsx");
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
}
```

Так нужно поступить со **всеми** используемыми COM-объектами.

Ваш код работы с Excel должен располагаться в блоке `try`, код закрытия и освобождения всех используемых ресурсов - в блоке `finally`.

Comment: Да, вы правы, но ошибка у меня была в другом. У меня в одной функции Excel открывается дважды: первый раз для загрузки данных, потом выполняются вычисления, и после этого Excel открывается во второй раз для сохранения. В этом случае Excel висит в диспетчере даже после выполнения указанных шагов. Вероятно, это работа оптимизатора. Теперь вынес загрузку и сохранение в отдельные функции и проблема исчезла.

Comment: @maestro - Интересно. Вы можете оформить своё решение как ответ (и даже принять его, вместо моего). И вполне можете плюсиков заработать, ведь это действительно другим пригодится в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (application != null)
{
   application.WorkbookBeforeClose -= new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(application_WorkbookBeforeClose);
   application.Quit();
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   process.WaitForExit(100);
}
```