# Код создания документа word вызывает ошибку проводника explorer.exe

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

Мой код (c# winforms vs2010) после закрытия вызывает появление ошибки проводника "explorer.exe" (на компьютерах с winxp и win7):

Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего может возникать ошибка проводника?
Привожу фрагмент кода:

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Word.Application word = null;
            Word.Documents docs = null;
            Word.Document doc = null;
            Word.Table oTable1 = null;
            Word.Table oTable = null;
            Word.Range oRange = null;
            Word.Paragraph oParag = null;
            Word.Paragraph oPara2 = null;
            Word.Template oTpl = null;

            try
            {
                if (Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD").Length == 0)
                {
                    word = new Word.Application();
                }
                else
                {
                    word = (Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
                }

                word.Visible = true;
                word.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;

                docs = (Word.Documents)word.Documents;
                object templateName = @"c:\a3.dot";
                object missing = Type.Missing;
                object openVisible = true;
                object documentType = Word.WdDocumentType.wdTypeDocument;
                doc = docs.Add(ref templateName, ref missing, ref documentType, ref openVisible);
                doc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;

                waitForm = new Form4();
                waitForm.TopMost = true;
                waitForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                waitForm.Show();
                if (waitForm.StartPosition == FormStartPosition.CenterParent)
                {
                    var x = Location.X + (Width - waitForm.Width) / 2;
                    var y = Location.Y + (Height - waitForm.Height) / 2;
                    waitForm.Location = new Point(Math.Max(x, 0), Math.Max(y, 0));
                }
                waitForm.Refresh();

//........

                object oRngEnd = word.Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast);
                object oAutoText = "table";
                object objTrue = true;
                oTpl = (Word.Template)doc.get_AttachedTemplate();
                oPara2 = doc.Paragraphs.Add(oRngEnd);
                oPara2.Range.Text = "";
                oPara2.Range.Font.Size = 11;
                doc.Paragraphs.Add(oRngEnd);
                doc.Paragraphs.Add(oRngEnd);
                doc.Paragraphs.Add(oRngEnd);
                doc.Paragraphs.Add(oRngEnd);
                oPara2.Range.Select();
                oTpl.AutoTextEntries.get_Item(ref oAutoText).Insert(word.Selection.Range, ref objTrue);

                word.Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst);

                object oTemplate_null = "";
                doc.set_AttachedTemplate(oTemplate_null);

                doc.ActiveWindow.View.DisplayPageBoundaries = true;
                doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.PageFit = Word.WdPageFit.wdPageFitBestFit;
                doc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;

                waitForm.Close();

                doc.Activate();
                word.Activate();
            }
            catch
            {
                waitForm.Close();

                if (oTpl != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oTpl); oTpl = null;
                if (oPara2 != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oPara2); oPara2 = null;
                if (oParag != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oParag); oParag = null;
                if (oRange != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oRange); oRange = null;
                if (oTable != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oTable); oTable = null;
                if (oTable1 != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oTable1); oTable1 = null;
                if (doc != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc); doc = null;
                if (docs != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(docs); docs = null;
                if (word != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(word); word = null;

                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (oTpl != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oTpl); oTpl = null;
                if (oPara2 != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oPara2); oPara2 = null;
                if (oParag != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oParag); oParag = null;
                if (oRange != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oRange); oRange = null;
                if (oTable != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oTable); oTable = null;
                if (oTable1 != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oTable1); oTable1 = null;
                if (doc != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc); doc = null;
                if (docs != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(docs); docs = null;
                if (word != null) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(word); word = null;
            }

        }
```

Ошибка стала возникать после добавления в приложение работы с Word

Скриншот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сведения:

> Сигнатура проблемы:
>   Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
>   Имя приложения: Explorer.EXE
>   Версия приложения: 6.1.7601.17514
>   Отметка времени приложения: 4ce7a144
>   Имя модуля с ошибкой: ntdll.dll
>   Версия модуля с ошибкой: 6.1.7601.18247
>   Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 521eaf24
>   Код исключения: c0000005
>   Смещение исключения: 0000000000028389
>   Версия ОС: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>   Код языка: 1049
>   Дополнительные сведения 1: 0056
>   Дополнительные сведения 2: 00565d7ce61ebbab216279960a6dd5b6
>   Дополнительные сведения 3: 2480
>   Дополнительные сведения 4: 2480f0afc22eea9532586bc57f7117f6

Comment: Попробуйте сначала определить точное место возникновния ошибки. У вас в коде много лишнего, не имеющего отношения к проблеме

Comment: Ошибка проводника возникает только после закрытия программы, через некоторое время (например, если щелкнуть мышкой на экране или в папке). В режиме отладки не видно.

Comment: Фигасе вы хакер: винду поломали. Я не уверен, но, думаю, дело в том, что вы не освобождаете COM-объекты. Я не вижу в вашем коде `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464115/184217

Comment: Добавила в код "Marshal.ReleaseComObject", но ошибка периодически все равно появляется! Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка в коде выше?

Comment: @defaultlocale Там скриншот в старых ревизиях есть, автор почему-то его выпилила. Обычный App crash

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не обратил внимания, спасибо.

Comment: @olga Вернул сведения об ошибке в текст вопроса. Теперь хочу попросить Вас помочь нам воспроизвести ошибку (создать [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Для начала нужно изолировать взаимодействие с Word от остального приложения. Для этого вынесите код из обработчика `Click` в отдельное новое консольное приложение. Попутно избавьтесь от ссылок на интерфейсные элементы (`Form4`), данные пропишите прямо в  коде. Соберите приложение и проверьте, вызывает ли выполнение такую же ошибку.

Answer (score 3):

Проводник просто так не падает от работы с WinForms и Word Automation. Типично проблема связана с багами в его расширениях. Чтобы выявить источник ошибки, попробуйте следующее:

1. Включить формирование дампов по [инструкции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2. Настроить студию на использование серверов символов Microsoft (Параметры - Отладка - Символы - Microsoft Symbol Servers)
3. После ошибки найти файл с расширением dmp в `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps`,  открыть в студии и войти в отладку
4. Изучите стек вызовов в момент падения, какие функции были вызваны и из каких DLL. Нужно смотреть на функции, расположенные ниже системных вызовов из ntdll и kernel32, это выглядит так:

[image: стек]

Если они относятся к стороннему ПО, попробуйте удалить или переустановить его. Если они относятся к ПО от Microsoft, нужно искать соответствующее исправление или сообщать о баге, если его нет.

Можно также использовать утилиту [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) для просмотра расширений проводника и отключения ненужных/багнутых.

Comment: Провела анализ файла dmp: IMAGE_NAME:  ntdll.dll

Comment: @olga IMAGE_NAME само по себе мало что дает. Нужно смотреть стек, все что находится в нем ниже системных вызовов (ntdll и kernel32), это выглядит как-то так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRXgz.png

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста имеет ли значение (для возникновения ошибки), закрыт созданный документ word до или после закрытия приложения. В моем коде word не закрывается кодом, т.е. пользователь может закрыть приложение и оставить word документ открытым.

Comment: @olga Думаю нет. Если бы программа что-то рушила в Word, падал бы сам Word, а не Explorer. Да и вообще, закрыть приложение и оставить документ открытым - вполне поддерживаемый сценарий.