# Очень много оперативной памяти поедается процессом - как чистить?

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора, выделение-памяти

Старый кусок кода которым я пользовался для чтения файлов в большой базе. В принципе самый основной. Запускался паралельно в нескольких Task-ах и выполнялся пока значения функций не начинали возвращать null, после чего записывалосл в файл excel и закрывало его.
Но вот жрало это всю свободную память (700мб) и в принципе потом почти не выполнялось. Работало медленно, и даже на 70 минуте не закончило работу.
Как снизить затраты оперативной памяти в принципе?

```
                Workbook wb;
                Worksheet ws;
                _Application Exce = new Excel.Application();
                wb = Exce.Workbooks.Add(1);
                ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];

                    foreach (List<IBOObjectCom> list in Counter)
                    {
                        foreach (IBOObjectCom obj in list)
                        {
                            var testc = ReadAllinRoot(obj);
                            if (testc != null)
                            {
                                Count.Add(testc);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                List<AttrObjectCom> atributes = ReadAllInList(obj);
                                if (atributes.Exists(x => x.NameAttr == "MNEMOCODE"))
                                {
                                    int b = 1;
                                    foreach (string atri in _nametar)
                                    {
                                    foreach (AttrObjectCom nameatri in atributes)
                                        {
                                            if (atri == nameatri.NameAttr)
                                            {
                                                try
                                                {
                                                    ws.Cells[a, b] = nameatri.DataAttr;
                                                }
                                                catch
                                                {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        b++;
                                    }
                                    a++;
                                    itsend = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Counter.Clear();
                    Counter.AddRange(Count);
                    Count.Clear();
```

ReadAllInRoot создает list объектов IBOObjectCom

ReadAllInList создает list атрибутов AttrObjectCom

Не стал приводить весь код, так как есть на данный момент только эта часть.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464115/184217 - как правильно использовать Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Answer (score 1):

При работе с COM-объектами (Interop) используйте [`Marshal.ReleaseComObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=netframework-4.7.2)