# Появляется ошибка при подсчёте количества страниц в word файле?

Tags: c#, .net, office, office-interop

У меня есть довольно простое приложение Windows Forms с использованием библиотеки Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, который считает страницы в указанном word файле. Идея простая: вводим путь к word файлу в TextBox и жмём кнопку для подсчёта.

```
OfficeApp.Application wordApp = new OfficeApp.Application();
OfficeApp.Document document = wordApp.Documents.Open(file.FullName);
int pageCount = document.ComputeStatistics(OfficeApp.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages);
document.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
document = null;
wordApp = null;
MessageBox.Show(pageCount.ToString());
```

Количество страниц мне выводится правильно, но сразу после вывода, появляется исключение System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ("Файл повреждён"), хотя файл абсолютно нормальный и корректно открывается. Также я заметил через диспетчер задач, что с каждым новым нажатием на кнопку создаётся новый процесс word, который остаётся существовать не смотря на то, что в коде есть инструкции по закрытию и обнулению объектов (document.Close(); wordApp.Quit(); document = null; wordApp = null;). Стоит упомянуть что код Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDoc);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp); также не работает в моём случае, процессы всё равно остаются висеть. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чём может быть проблема? Может ли это быть связано с тем, что у меня не лицензионный Word и после открытия файла появляется диалоговое окно мастера активации Microsoft Office? Может кто-то подскажет альтернативный способ подсчёта страниц.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464115/184217

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не закрывается Excel в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464086/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-excel-%d0%b2-c)

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой метод:

```
 private void LoadInDataTable() // обработка файла и выгрузка данных в datatable
    {
        var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        if (excelApp != null)
        {
            Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: Path, 0, true,
                5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true,
                1, 0);

            Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[CurrentSheet + 1];
            Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;
            string cellValue = "";
            string[] cellArr = new string[colCount];
            TableColumnsList.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
            {
                TableColumnsList.Add(new ObservableCollection<TableColumns>
                {
                    new()
                    {
                        Count = i
                    }
                });
            }

            CurrentColumnLeft = 0;
            CurrentColumnRight = 0;
            GenerateDatatableColumnsAndRows(colCount);
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    Range range = (excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range);
                    try
                    {
                        cellValue = range.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        cellValue = "";
                    }

                    cellArr[j - 1] = cellValue;
                }

                Table.Rows.Add(cellArr); //добавление в дататэйбл целой строки из массива
            }

            excelWorkbook.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
    }
```